# Ubuntu: Enabling Media Keys for google play music

Tags: google-play, keyboard-shortcuts, spotify, dbus, ubuntu-18.04

so recently i switched from spotify to google play music

with spotify ubuntu app there was this [tricks](https://fabianlee.org/2016/05/25/ubuntu-enabling-media-keys-for-spotify/) to kind of proxy keyboard media shortcuts to be used for spotify too

since google hasn't made an official desktop app for music is there a way to send these signals to the play music tab in the browser ?

---

I've found this [unofficial desktop version](https://www.googleplaymusicdesktopplayer.com/), same question for this app would be asked but i doubt answer would be different from the original question.

Answer (score 0):

> since google hasn't made an official desktop app for music is there a way to send these signals to the play music tab in the browser ?

No. You would need a browser extension.